# FileSystemException appears on maven build in wsl2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL2 on my Windows, where I build a maven project with WildFly.
The compilation fails with following error. On Windows this issue doesn't appear and when I run Ubuntu in Virtualbox, it doesn't appear as well:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /home/user/bitbucket/trax/trax/trax-release/target/dist/wildfly/standalone/data/content/content2467258569631006810/content/rdTemplate/yui3/build/file-flash/file-flash-min.js: Too many open files
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:371)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:422)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:156)
        at org.jboss.as.deployment-repository@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.repository.HashUtil.getRecursiveContentStream(HashUtil.java:120)
```

How can I fix this

Comment: Have you tried to ask Microsoft Support ?

Comment: The issue is Linux-related

Comment: looks more like WSL related.

Comment: I did some reasearch and it has to do with the ulimit parameter, but the approaches are different in the resources that I find.